# Combining data divided between multiple columns after pivoting pandas data table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame that is shaped as follows:

```
TIME   2015-07-25_10:24:49    2015-07-25_10:24:51   2015-07-25_10:24:46 ...
NAME        
Ed          Kitchen                 None                 Office
Jane         None                Dining Room              None
Robert       None                  Kitchen                None
Louisa       None                   None                 Office
   .
   .
   .
```

This dataframe can be reproduced with this snippet:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

names = ['Ed', 'Jane', 'Robert', 'Louisa', 'Ed']
locations = ['Kitchen', 'Dining Room', 'Kitchen', 'Office', 'Office']
times = [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 25, 10, 24, 49), 
         datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 25, 10, 24, 51),
         datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 25, 10, 24, 51),
         datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 25, 10, 24, 46),
         datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 25, 10, 24, 46)]

data = {'TIME': times, 
        'NAME': names,
        'LOCATIONS': locations}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df = df.pivot(index='NAME', columns='TIME', values='LOCATIONS')
```

From this data frame, I want to produce a data frame with the columns collapsed into time ranges:

```
TIME   2015-07-25, 10:23-10:25   2015-07-25, 10:25-10:27   ...
NAME        
Ed            Kitchen                     Office
Jane        Dining Room                    None
Robert        Kitchen                      None
Louisa        Office                       None 
   .
   .
   .
```

The idea being to 'collapse' the given data down into as few column bins as possible to eliminate as many NaNs as possible.  The conversion in the columns is from time stamps to a range of time stamps. So, rather that 'Ed has been in the kitchen for two minutes,' it's 'At some point in the two minute range between 10:23 and 10:25, Ed was in the kitchen.' The last entry would ideally be pushed into the next time stamp range, even though it actually occurred in the first one.

Feel free to let me know if I can clarify in any way. Thanks in advance -

Comment: What do you mean by 'time bins'? Could you provide a snippet of the desired output?

Comment: I'm referring to the last code block (the desired output), where the columns now represent two-minute intervals instead of individual time stamps. Does that answer your question?

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to change the timestamps to timespans/timedeltas. Let's say 'Ed' has been for two minutes in the 'Kitchen'. And at the 'Office' for the next time span. What should happen to the very last entry since we cannot calculate the duration he stayed there?

Comment: [Question edited above] Almost - the conversion is from time stamps to a range of time stamps. So, rather that 'Ed has been in the kitchen for two minutes,' it's 'At some point in the two minute range between 10:23 and 10:25, Ed was in the kitchen.' The last entry would ideally be pushed into the next time stamp range, even though it actually occurred in the first one.

Comment: pandas has a (time-based) resample() method ( http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) that might be what you're after. You could use it to keep one column every 5min or so, and just need to specify how to aggregate several logs into one (say if Ed was in Kichen and then Office during a 5min window).